# Scale textsizes for different screen sizes

Tags: android

I have some layouts and I want to adjust my textsize to the screen size. I used sp for all my sizes, but when I switch to my tablet my text still looks to small.

Is there a common scale formula or something to simply do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `View.getHeight()` and `View.getWidth()` and apply your logic accordingly.

**OR**

Use this :

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int height = display.getHeight();
```

**OR**

To get screen size in inches, try :

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels/dm.xdpi,2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels/dm.ydpi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
Log.d("debug","Screen inches : " + screenInches);
```

Comment: how does this solve the question? This just fetches the screen size

Comment: After you get the screen size, you can scale your textview accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

use `dip` instead of `sp` but I'm sure the default textsize depends on its container e.g. a textView or a Button

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
android:textSize="dip"
```

for eg. `10 dip,20 dip`